# How do I use 7Zip to open a file in an archive with a specific program?

Tags: windows, 7-zip, file-archiver

Let's say there's an XML file in an archive, and I want to open it in Firefox but just double-clicking it will open it in notepad, the default program. How do I select the program?

Comment: This is not the behavior I have at all.  I get "How do you want to open this file?" from the 7z GUI.  I believe that this is because I have never toggled the "Always use this app" checkbox.  So are you asking how do you change the default or how do you get the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog back?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I wanted to keep the default app but have the "Open with" dialog as option when right-clicking, as I now have. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the editor in <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options...</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd>. Choose the executable and save.
Then <kbd>RMB</kbd> on a file and choose <kbd>Edit</kbd> or select it and press <kbd>F4</kbd>

Alternatively, if you want to keep another app there, you could set app for e.g. `Preview` to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe` and then <kbd>RMB</kbd> on a file and <kbd>Preview</kbd> it or select it and press <kbd>F3</kbd>. This will display the Windows menu to choose any application, with recommendations per file type.

One more alternative is to choose <kbd>Open externally</kbd> option in <kbd>RMB</kbd> menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>). This will open it in default system app.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I found that this won't work for me since the xml will only open properly if the associated xsl and css files are available, but this will be useful in other situations.